# Network images disappeared after asp.net site deployed to IIS 7 (Windows 2008 R2)

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, localhost

I have a web application which shows network images when I ran it thru localhost. But when I host the site on IIS on the same server, the network path is not working. IIS site is not giving any permission issue nither it is giving "x" sign (404-Not found) for images..

I also provided the full permission to the system user over IIS site. Still, images are not loading.

I tried with the virtual directory (mapped image folder) but no luck.

Please suggest. Screenshots for ref:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the answer to my question from [Microsoft forum](https://forums.iis.net/p/1238291/2140089.aspx?p=True&t=636577113094850983)

**I assume the IIS doesn't support this kind of path**. For that, I need to create a virtual directory to map it to the image file. Then use a domain account which has enough permission to access the image file in IIS Manager->site level->virtual directory level->basic setting->connect as->specific user->domain user.

Then only need to modify the path.

I already tried virtual path earlier but this time I have provided enough permission to access.

[image]